# How can the terminal on VS Code be fixed?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have some problems with the terminal of VSCode. When I try to open the terminal it's saying that "The terminal shell path "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe" does not exist" ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oP6E7.png)). How can I fix it, help me please.

Comment: I'm using `"C:\\\\Program Files\\\\Git\\\\bin\\\\bash.exe"` with all those escapes for the `terminal.integrated.shell.windows` is that what you have?

Comment: Did you check if bash is installed at that location? If not, you either need to install it, or change the `terminal.integrated.shell.windows` setting to the right place.
Btw, @Mark, I have only half the backslashes there... Did you edit that in the editor?

Comment: I agree with [Joep Beusenberg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1531122/joep-beusenberg) (+1). You most probably don't have Git installed. Check by open Explorer to ```C:\Program Files\Git\bin\```, and if that folder is missing, install [Git](https://git-scm.com/download/win)

Answer (score 3):

If you got "The terminal process failed to launch: Path to shell executable "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe" does not exist. VSCODE" in VSCode, it's time to change the settings and change the path of the file where your git is located.

I did encountered the same issue, and when I had VSCode in my old system, it had the old path pre-configured, and if you sign-in to your VSCode in new system, you might want to change your path of the file where the git was initially installed.

To do the changes,

1. Open VSCode >> Setting ("Ctrl + comma(,)" ). This will open up your settings in VSCode.
2. Search for `terminal.integrated.shell.windows` or Got to "`Terminal >> Integerated >> Automation profiles >> Windows`". If you have Linux/ other operating system you will find the same settings.
3. Click on "`Edit in Settings.json`"

Check the image provided below.

[VSCode Settings for Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKW5A.png)

4. Once you opened the "`Edit in Settings.json`", find the term "`terminal.integrated.shell.windows`", and change the path of your git location.

This will fix the VSCode issue.

I hope it works for you! Thank you.

Check the image provided below.

[terminal.integrated.shell.windows settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUPr0.png)

Comment: NOTE: once you have done the above steps, restart vscode.

Answer (score 0):

Select Default Profile as Git bash by clicking down arrow next to plus icon in the terminal.
Please check this documentation
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_terminal-profiles

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.